# Angular Implementing multi search filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search

I am using the angular [advanced search box](http://dnauck.github.io/angular-advanced-searchbox/) and I want to implement a custom filter in my angular page but I am having trouble figuring out how to handle a string of requirements in a query. Let's say I have several objects that follow the following format:

```
{
    "displayName":"John",
    "gender":"male",
    "type":"customer",
    "items": 3,
}
```

I would want to be able to search in plain english `Anyone who's name is John and is of type Customer". Here is my angular search code so far:

```
app.filter('infoFilter', function() {
    return function(data, query) {
        var output = [];
        var index;

        //loop over the original array
        angular.forEach(data, function(row, index) {
            angular.forEach(query, function(input, value) {
                if(input) {
                    if(angular.isNumber(row[value]) && row[value] == input) {
                        output.push(row);
                    } else if(!angular.isNumber(row[value]) && row[value].toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                        output.push(row);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        if(query) {
            return data;
        } else {
            return output;
        }
    }
});
```

The query comes in as an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "displayName":"John"
}
```

This works perfectly fine for 1 search parameter. So if I searched for `John` my table would update to show all entries with the name of john. However, this wouldn't really work for multi search parameters. So if the query looked like this:

```
{
    "displayName":"John",
    "gender":"Female"
}
```

I need to apply all the parameters at once before i do `output.push(row)`. How exactly would I go about doing this?

Comment: those multiple parameter should work in what way AND/OR condition..? single record should match both query, or any record will have one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to filter the rows where all query parameters apply (AND). I modified your code slightly to achieve this behavior.

```
app.filter('infoFilter', function() {
    return function(data, query) {
        var output = [];
        var index;

        //loop over the original array
        angular.forEach(data, function(row, index) {

            var pushRow = true;

            angular.forEach(query, function(input, value) {
                if(input) {
                    if(angular.isNumber(row[value]) && row[value] == input) {
                        return;
                    } else if(!angular.isNumber(row[value]) && row[value].toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                pushRow = false;
            });

            if (pushRow) {
                output.push(row);
            }
        });

        // This bit also seems to be the wrong way around in your code.
        if(!query) {
            return data;
        } else {
            return output;
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

Here is also an optimized version of the same filter using javascripts [built in array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

```
app.filter('infoFilter', function() {
    return function(data, query) {
        if(!query || !data) {
            return data;
        }

        return data.filter(function(row) {
            return Object.keys(query).every(function(key) {
                var rowValue = row[key];
                var queryValue = query[key];

                return (angular.isNumber(rowValue) && rowValue == input) ||
                        (angular.isString(rowValue) && rowValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryValue.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: this is perfect but for some reason I keep getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`. Any idea what that is about?

Comment: Probably because data is undefined.

Comment: yep, that was it. Thank you! I have a question about how to extract operators but I'll make a new post about that.