# Angular Extracting Operators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, search

I want to write some code to parse a search string. My [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755837/angular-implementing-multi-search-filter) shows my filter code thanks to Scraph. Now I need to handle the following search scenarios:

1. `age>10`
2. `age>=10`
3. `items!=3`

The following code detects if there's a number in the string:

```
if(queryValue.match(/\d+/g)) {
   $log.debug("Regex detected numbers");
}
```

I've tested this and it works with an input like `>=10`. Now I need to extract the `>=` and apply that to my search. I can create an array or operators like so:

```
var operators = ['>', '>=', '<', '<=', "!="]
```

And then have a for loop to figure out which operator it is then extract the number portion and do the filtering. However that seems overly verbose so I'm wondering if there's a cleaner solution to my problem.

Comment: Maybe dumb comment, but... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp ?

Comment: this will suffice :- https://regex101.com/r/qK8eZ8/1

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you need. Please show what you want to achieve with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only the 5 mentioned cases above, the following will work

```
[><]=?|!=
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qK8eZ8/1)

*JS Demo (not Angular JS)*

```js
var re = /([><]=?|!=)/; 
var str = ['>=', '<=', '=', '!=', '<', '>', '!', 'abc>=234'];

str.forEach(function(number) {
  if (number.match(re))
      document.writeln(number.match(re)[1] + '<br>');
});
```

**[Angular JS Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9uGNWC8KH4ed2BGvOiZ1?p=preview)**